# Indentation of glossaries and index in TOC not synchronized with other unnumbered chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, indentation, glossaries, indexing

I would like to synchronize the indentation of unnumbered chapters in the TOC to the position of the number of chapters (preferred) or at least synchronize them while using KOMA-Script, glossaries and imakeindex under LuLaTex.

toc=indentunnumbered does not help (there is problem with the indentation of index)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\documentclass[toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[
    variant     =   german,
    spelling    =   new,
]{german}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[
    acronym     =   true,
    toc         =   true,
    numberline  =   true,
    nopostdot   =   true,
    section     =   chapter,
    nomain      =   true,
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{hyperref}       

\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
        of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
        make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
        program that implements that API}}

\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
        Programming Interface}, first={Application
        Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}
\makeindex[intoc]
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\printglossary[                                     
    type            =   \acronymtype,
    title           =   Acronyms,
    toctitle        =   Acronyms,
    style           =   list,
    nonumberlist    =   true,
]

\addchap{Motivation}
\chapter{Chapter}
\index{Alpha}
\index{Alpha!Beta}
\index{Alpha!Beta1}
\index{Alpha!Beta2}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Gamma}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Delta}
\index{Alpha}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\addchap{Abstract}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the indentation of Acronyms in the ToC remove `numberline=true` from `glossaries` options:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\documentclass[toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[
    variant     =   german,
    spelling    =   new,
]{german}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[
    acronym     =   true,
    toc         =   true,
    %numberline  =   true,% <- remove this
    nopostdot   =   true,
    section     =   chapter,
    nomain      =   true,
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{hyperref}       

\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
        of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
        make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
        program that implements that API}}

\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
        Programming Interface}, first={Application
        Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}
\makeindex[intoc]
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents    

\printglossary[                                     
    type            =   \acronymtype,
    title           =   Acronyms,
    toctitle        =   Acronyms,
    style           =   list,
    nonumberlist    =   true,
]

\addchap{Motivation}
\chapter{Chapter}
\index{Alpha}
\index{Alpha!Beta}
\index{Alpha!Beta1}
\index{Alpha!Beta2}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Gamma}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Delta}
\index{Alpha}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\addchap{Abstract}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

---

If the index should respect option `toc=indentunnumbered` add `\indexsetup{level=\addchap}` and remove option `intoc` for `\makeindex`:

```
%\documentclass{scrbook}
\documentclass[toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[
    variant     =   german,
    spelling    =   new,
]{german}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[
    acronym     =   true,
    toc         =   true,
    numberline  =   true,
    nopostdot   =   true,
    section     =   chapter,
    nomain      =   true,
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{level=\addchap}% <- added

\usepackage{hyperref}       

\newglossaryentry{apig}{name={API},
    description={An Application Programming Interface (API) is a particular set
        of rules and specifications that a software program can follow to access and
        make use of the services and resources provided by another particular software
        program that implements that API}}

\newglossaryentry{api}{type=\acronymtype, name={API}, description={Application
        Programming Interface}, first={Application
        Programming Interface (API)\glsadd{apig}}, see=[Glossary:]{apig}}
\makeindex% <- remove option intoc
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary[                                     
    type            =   \acronymtype,
    title           =   Acronyms,
    toctitle        =   Acronyms,
    style           =   list,
    nonumberlist    =   true,
]

\addchap{Motivation}
\chapter{Chapter}
\index{Alpha}
\index{Alpha!Beta}
\index{Alpha!Beta1}
\index{Alpha!Beta2}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Gamma}
\index{Alpha!Gamma!Delta}
\index{Alpha}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\addchap{Abstract}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! That bothered me for some time but sometimes the solution can be so simple and you don't see it.